# SelectionSorting in c++ (Error : EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

I just recently learned to do selection sorting an array. I am also using X-Code on a mac.
I thought I did everything correctly, but I seem to keep getting this error message on the if statement :

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x7fff5fc00000).

What am I doing wrong?

```
using namespace std;

void selectionSorting(int array[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; n++)
    {
        int min = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] < array[min])   //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x7fff5fc00000)
                min = j;
        }
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
  int n = 10;
  int array[]= {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

  selectionSorting(array, n);

  for(int x=0; x < n; x++)
  {
    cout << array[x] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `for(... n++)`. You can easily find such errors with a debugger, so I suggest learning to use one.

Comment: n is a constant so a const declaration would have spotted this.

Comment: Side note: Selection sort is a rather inefficient algorithm, it's fine for learning programming, but of little worth almost anywhere else... Just keep that in mind, in general, you should be fine with `std::sort`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error at `for(int i = 0; i < n-1; n++)`. It should be `for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` (iterate through the elements of the array).

Also EXC_BAD_ACCESS suggests that your are trying to access a piece of memory that is no longer accessible or it doesn't go well with the intended use.

See that this occurs at `if(array[j] < array[min])`, which is obvious because j is going beyond the array length as you do `n++`.

As suggested in the comments try using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful!